# Is there a way to rescale the world map in R in order to only show the northern part of america?

Tags: r, maps, visualization

I try to visualize some US-flights in R, however some of them are going to Hawaii and Puerto Rico so they won't be displayed if I change "world" to "states" within the map() function.

[image]

I already tried to change the focus of the map but did not find a way to do that. I use the map package. Does anyone know how to rescale? On the internet I found the following data:

```
left=-179, bottom=15, right=-65, top=75
```

The map is created by:

```
map("world", col="white", border="gray10", fill=TRUE, bg="grey30")
```

Comment: Which package are you using to get the `map` function?

Comment: I use the library('maps')

Comment: xlim & ylim, check `?map` for details. `maps::map(xlim = c(-180,-50), ylim = c(10,85))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments.

```
map("world", col="white", border="gray10", fill=TRUE, 
    bg="grey30", xlim=c(-179,-64), ylim=c(15,75))
```